# Starting Activity on Startup

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

Hey friends, I want to know how to start an activity on startup of the phone. ?

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register Broadcast receiver with intent filter "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
Good example can can be found here http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

Answer (score 1):

You have to register Your application for Broadcast

**http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-ii-intent-receivers/**